# Intellij findbugs in english

Tags: intellij-idea, findbugs

I'm using intellij (10.5) + findbugs under windows.
My problem is that findbugs report me the errors in french.

Only way I could find to have findbugs in english is to do change in regional settings in windows control panel (Control panel\Region and language\formats : changed from french to english).

Is there any other way to tell findbugs to use english ?

Comment: Try adding `-Duser.language=en` in `IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language can be overridden with `-Duser.language=en` line in `IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions`.